# Can this be done with Stokes' Theorem? (Exercise)

Tags: conic-sections, line-integrals, stokes-theorem

Problem description:

Let $\gamma$ denote the curve of intersection of the two surfaces $z=x^2+y^2$ and $z=1+2x$. Calculate the line integral $W=\oint_\gamma \boldsymbol{F}\cdot d\boldsymbol{r}$, where $\boldsymbol{F}=(0,x,-y)$ and $d\boldsymbol{r}=(dx,dy,dz)$.

Now, by easy substiution of the first equation into the second we get the realtionship between $x$ and $y$ as $(x-1)^2 + y^2=2$. Parametrization gives $x=1+\sqrt{2}\cos{t}\quad$ and $\quad y=\sqrt{2}\sin{t}$. Lastly the complete parametrization of the curve $\gamma$ is $\boldsymbol{r}=(1+\sqrt{2}\cos{t},\sqrt{2}\sin{t},3+2\sqrt{2}\cos{t})$, where I have inserted the new expression for $x$ into the second equation.

Well, from here we can can calculate $W$ over $0\leq t \leq 2\pi$ and get the answer of $6\pi$ relatively quickly. But I am wondering if Stokes' Theorem could be used here? My textbook implies it could be done. The result is then

$W=\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}}\iint_S dS$.

How do I know what the area of S is, that I am guessing is an ellipse? It shoud evidently become $2\sqrt{5}\pi$, so maybe the axises are $2$ and $\sqrt{5}$, respectively? But how do I reach this result otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an closed path integral, you can use stokes theorem.

$\oint_\gamma F\cdot \ d\gamma = \iint \nabla \times F\cdot dS$

Where $S$ is the elliptical disc in the plane bounded by the paraboloid.

$\nabla \times F = (-1,0,1)$

$dS = (-\frac {\partial z}{\partial x},\frac {\partial z}{\partial y}, 1)\ dA= (-2,0,1)\ dA$

$\iint 3\ dA = 3 A$

A is the area of the ellipse projected onto the $xy$ plane (which is a circle).

$6\pi$

Regarding, 
$W=\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}}\iint_S dS$

$S$ is an ellipse with semi-major axis equal to $\sqrt {10}$, and semi-minor axis equal to $\sqrt 2$

$(\frac {3}{\sqrt 5})(\pi )(\sqrt {10})({\sqrt 2}) = 6\pi$

Comment: I have some trouble understanding the projection of the area element dS onto the z=0 plane. You differentiate z wrt to x and y, I have seen this somewhere - is this a parametrization of the plane with z as parameter? And then A represents a circle with radius sqrt(2), as seen in the equation (x−1)^2 + y^2 = 2 ?

Comment: Generally, $dS = (\frac {\partial x}{\partial u}, \frac {\partial y}{\partial u}. \frac {\partial z}{\partial u}) \times (\frac {\partial x}{\partial v}, \frac {\partial y}{\partial v}, \frac {\partial z}{\partial v})\ du\ dv.$  Using parameters $x=x, y=y, z = f(x,y)$ gives $(1, 0,  \frac {\partial z}{\partial x}) \times (0, 1, \frac {\partial z}{\partial y}) = (-\frac {\partial z}{\partial x},-\frac {\partial z}{\partial y},1)\ dx\ dy.$ This is a very useful thing to know.  And yes, $A$ is the disk $(x-1)^2 + y^2 \le 2$

Comment: This is great, I believe I understand now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have an closed path integral, you can use stokes theorem.

$\oint_\gamma F\cdot \ d\gamma = \iint \nabla \times F\cdot dS$

Where $S$ is the elliptical disc on the plane bounded by the paraboloid.

$\nabla \times F = (-1,0,1)$

$dS = (-\frac {\partial z}{\partial x},-\frac {\partial z}{\partial y}, 1)\ dA= (-2,0,1)\ dA$

$A$ is the projection of $S$ onto the $xy$ plane (which is a circle)

$\iint 3\ dA = 3 A$

$6\pi$

Comment: Thank you  very much, just to be sure we are on the same page, you mean the disc inside the paraboloid, not cylinder right?

Comment: Somehow my answer was duplicated.  Not sure how that happened.